# Hammer.js set distance to 0 when pan direction is triggered

Tags: javascript, hammer.js

I'm trying to modify Hammer.js so when pan is triggered, I wanna equal distance to 0 so user needs to move enough to trigger pan again without cancel pan.

Now when pan distance is bigger than pan threshold, if you move 1px to any direction pan direction is triggered.

Also I don't want to force cancel pan when it's triggered because user needs to click again to start pan event.

This is the fire code when pan direction is triggered.

```
emit: function(input) {
    this.pX = input.deltaX;
    this.pY = input.deltaY;

    var direction = directionStr(input.direction);
    if (direction) {
        this.manager.emit(this.options.event + direction, input);
    }

    this._super.emit.call(this, input);
}
```

I've tried to modify input.distance to 0, but it only affects variable in that function, not the real value.

Then I've tried adding this:

```
    mc.add( new Hammer.Pan({ direction: Hammer.DIRECTION_ALL, threshold: 10 }) );
```

But this cancel current pan event.

Also tried to cancel current pan and activate it to equal distance to 0 but it also cancel current pan...

```
    mc.get('pan').set({ enable: false });
    mc.get('pan').set({ enable: true });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve my question with some weird code, **use it if you only use pan functionality or all threshold are equal**.

Add this lines to the start of the file:

```
...
var abs = Math.abs;
var now = Date.now;
//Add emitPanDirection
var emitPanDirection;
...
```

Then add this to computeInputData function

```
function computeInputData(manager, input) {
....
    input.angle = getAngle(offsetCenter, center);
    input.distance = getDistance(offsetCenter, center);

    //This will reset firstInput.center and firstMultiple.center to current mouse location
    if(input.distance > manager.options.preset[3][1].threshold){
        emitPanDirection=true;
        session.firstInput.center=getCenter(pointers);
        session.firstMultiple.center=getCenter(pointers);
    }
....
}
```

Change this code in inherit(PanRecognizer, AttrRecognizer, {...

```
attrTest: function(input) {
    return AttrRecognizer.prototype.attrTest.call(this, input) &&
        (this.state & STATE_BEGAN || (!(this.state & STATE_BEGAN) && this.directionTest(input)));
},
```

For this one:

```
attrTest: function(input) {
    return (AttrRecognizer.prototype.attrTest.call(this, input) && this.directionTest(input));
},
```

And finally add this if in emit: function(input) in the same PanRecognizer

```
emit: function(input) {
    //Need to add this if or emit will emit pandirection twice
    if(emitPanDirection){
        emitPanDirection=false;
        this.pX = input.deltaX;
        this.pY = input.deltaY;

        var direction = directionStr(input.direction);
        if (direction) {
            this.manager.emit(this.options.event + direction, input);
        }

        this._super.emit.call(this, input);
    }
}
```